# python dictionary question

Tags: python, django

All,

This is the request from the template that i get

```
u'subjects': [u'7', u'4', u'5', u'3', u'2', u'1']
```

In my views how to extract the values like `7 4 5 3 2 1`

How do i extract the above sequence from

```
new_subjects=request.POST.get('subjects')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request.POST` is an instance of [QueryDict](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) which have a method named [getlist](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) that returns a list of values for the given key.

Example:

```
>>> new_subjects = request.POST.getlist('subjects')
>>> print new_subjects
[u'7', u'4', u'5', u'3', u'2', u'1']
```

See [gnibbler's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155246/python-dictionary-question/2155345#2155345) for converting the list items to integers.

Answer (score 5):

Something like the following:

```
try:
    int_subjects = [int(x) for x in new_subjects]
except ValueError:
    #There was an error parsing.
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a bare `except` clause.

Comment: I didn't remember at the time what the right error was. I figured it was either googleable or someone here would know.

Comment: It's easy.  Run Python.  Type `int("hi mom")` and you'll know.  That's what I did.  I don't rely on memory -- Gin has destroyed what little I had.

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
    int_subjects = map(int, new_subjects)
except ValueError:
    #There was an error parsing.
```

Using timeit in ipython shows that map is slightly faster than the comprehension in this case

```
In [99]: timeit map(int,new_subjects)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.81 µs per loop

In [100]: timeit [int(x) for x in new_subjects]
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: +1 for trying to optimizing another answer (and doing so successfully)